# VS2010 and VS2012 and C++11 error C2059: syntax error : '...' how to get around?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c++11, visual-studio-2012, variadic-templates

I try to compile [simple C++11 code](http://ideone.com/AlDoKA) (I primaraly target vs2010 and also as secondary option vs 2012) [they say](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13792100/1056328) it shall compile and [is compilable on some modern compilers](http://liveworkspace.org/code/KKkbu$1)
And so I wonder how to compile code containing structs like:

```
struct C {
    A *_first__;
    B *_second__;
     C(A * _first__, B * _second__):_first__(_first__), _second__(_second__) {
    } template < typename K, typename ... T > static auto _a_caller__(K * k, T && ... args)->decltype(k->a(std::forward < T > (args) ...)) {
    return k->a(std::forward < T > (args)...);
    }
    template < typename...T > auto a(T &&...args)->decltype(_a_caller__(_first__, std::forward < T > (args)...)) {
        return _a_caller__(_first__, std::forward < T > (args)...);
    }
    template < typename...T > auto a(T &&...args)->decltype(_a_caller__(_second__, std::forward < T > (args)...)) {
        return _a_caller__(_second__, std::forward < T > (args)...);
    }
    template < typename K, typename...T > static auto _b_caller__(K * k, T && ... args)->decltype(k->b(std::forward < T > (args) ...)) {
        return k->b(std::forward < T > (args)...);
    }
    template < typename...T > auto b(T &&...args)->decltype(_b_caller__(_first__, std::forward < T > (args)...)) {
        return _b_caller__(_first__, std::forward < T > (args)...);
    }
    template < typename...T > auto b(T &&...args)->decltype(_b_caller__(_second__, std::forward < T > (args)...)) {
        return _b_caller__(_second__, std::forward < T > (args)...);
    }
};
```

In vs 2010 and if not possible there in vs2012?

Answer (score 4):

Variadic templates aren't supported neither in VS2010 nor in VS2012: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh567368.aspx 
They are supported in VS2012 CTP though: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/11/02/visual-c-c-11-and-the-future-of-c.aspx

Also see [Variadic Template in VS 2012 (Visual C++ November 2012 CTP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13238408/variadic-template-in-vs-2012-visual-c-november-2012-ctp) if you intend to use the CTP.

Comment: well it steel does not compile even with  Variadic Template in VS 2012 (Visual C++ November 2012 CTP) installed